# How to wait for a loop with promises to complete to execute a method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I want to execute a loop with promises, but I want to execute a method only after the loop completes.

This is a similar example of that I want to do

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

console.log('start');
array.forEach((i) => {
  setTimeout(()=> console.log(i), 3000);        
});
console.log('end');
```

this the result i got.

```
start
end
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` is asynchronous, but is not **thenable** like a promise. If your direct question is to execute your code when all the **timeouts** end, then it should be done as follows:

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let numberOfTimeoutsToBeExecuted = array.length;
// keep track of the number of timeouts that have finished execution
let numberOfTimeoutsExecuted = 0;

console.log('start');
array.forEach((i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i),
    numberOfTimeoutsExecuted += 1;
    // execute your code when the last timeout has finished execution
    if (numberOfTimeoutsToBeExecuted === numberOfTimeoutsExecuted) {
      console.log('end');
    }
  }, 3000);       
});
```

However, if you want to wait for multiple **promises** to finish execution, the following is the best way to do this:

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const promises = [];

console.log('start');
array.forEach((i) => {
    // add all promises that will be executed into array
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(()=> {
        console.log(i);
        resolve();
      }, 3000);
    }));
});

// execute all promises here
Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log('end'));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easily doable with something like [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) once you know how.

The key is to create an array of Promises and then call [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on it.

But before I can show we need to make some adjustments:

First let's wrap [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) to return a promise:

```
function delay(amount) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, amount);
    });
}
```

Then change the code to push all created promises onto an array:

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let promises = [];

async function doSomething(i) {
    console.log(i);

    await delay(3000);
}

console.log('start');
array.forEach((i) => {
    const promise = doSomething(i);

    promises.push(promise);
});
```

Here `doSomething` is doing the asynchronous work.

Lastly, we wait for all Promises to be resolved with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
await Promise.all(promises);

console.log('end');
```

Gives:

```
start
a
b
c
end
```

```js
function delay(amount) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, amount);
    });
}

const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let promises = [];

async function doSomething(i) {
    console.log(i);

    await delay(3000);
}

console.log('start');
array.forEach((i) => {
    const promise = doSomething(i);

    promises.push(promise);
});

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log('end');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is do the following:

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

console.log('start');
const promises = [];
array.forEach((i) => {
    promises.push(new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i)
        resolve()
    }, 3000)))
})

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    console.log('end');
})
```

Comment: I've just added code to solve and illustrates how to achieve what you're asked. But in terms of code organization, I would made in a different way, sure. Like the others that answered this question did.